# Pointing a bone towards an axis (in pose mode)

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, transforms

So I just spent the better part of a day looking everywhere for a solution, to no avail.

Basically, I wanted to rotate a bone to where it points perfectly towards an axis (the global axis, not a local axis) in pose mode, preferably without using object constraints. Like "snapping" a bone's rotation towards one of the 6 axes, if you will.

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: could you not just set the rotation to be a multiple of 90 degrees via the properties panel?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms - that only works if the bone is created aligned to the axis. An arm bone in the t-pose may point down 36 degrees, making a zero pose mode rotation not aligned to any global axis. To get it horizontal you need to move it up 36 degrees in pose mode.

Comment: I think you will need to use a constraint. It would be position an empty, add a trackto constraint, apply the transform and delete the constraint. An addon could be made to do it, don't know if there are any existing.

Comment: Yeah, what sambler said is primarily why I can't simply set the rotation to  a multiple of 90 degrees.
I'll try the constraint thing later and see if that works for me.

Comment: @sambler When you say "apply the transform", what exactly do you mean? I positioned an empty, used a constraint and got the bone pointing upward, but I'm stuck at that. I assume you mean applying the constraint transformation, but I do not know how to do such; I know it's not like modifiers where you can simply apply the transformation with a click of a button.

Comment: `Ctrl-A->Apply Visual Transform to Pose`. You can also `Insert Keyframe->Visual Rotation` to add keyframes.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I'll give it a try later and see if it does the trick.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much @sambler! Also, is there any way to close or lock a question since it's been indirectly answered? I'm entirely new to StackExchange in general...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you ask for a way without constraints, I think you will need to use one, at least temporarily, to get the bone positioned.

- Align an empty to the head of the bone.
- Move the empty on the global axis you want to align to.
- Add a TrackTo constraint to the bone and set the empty as the target.

Now that the bone is pointing the direction you want, you can use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*->Apply Visual Transform to Pose* and delete the constraint.

You can also use <kbd>I</kbd>*->Visual Rotation* to keyframe the values used after constraints have been applied to the bone.